# Import DataSet into SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a very large DataSet containing about 160.000 records. If I loop trough the dataset and import every record, it can take about 20 minutes before the complete dataset is imported into the SQL Server.

Isn't there a faster way for importing the dataset at once in the database?

The dataset is created from a file I process which the user provides, then I have 1 table called lets say "ImportTable" containing about 14 columns. The columns correspond with the columns in the DataSet.

I use Visual Studio 2010 professional with c#.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a close look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28VS.80%29.aspx) class.

It's a C# component (no external app), it takes a DataSet or DataTable as input, and copies that into SQL Server in a bulk fashion. Should be significantly faster than doing a row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR) insert operation...

Better yet: you don't even need to import your entire data set into memory - you can define a `SqlDataReader` on your base data, and pass that to `SqlBulkCopy` to read from the `SqlDataReader` and bulk insert into SQL Server.

Comment: Cool that's the answer I was looking for... :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) command line utility. It lets you load data directly from a file into a table in the database. Depending on how the user generated file looks, you may need to re-format it, but if it has a simple delimited format you can probably use it *as-is* with bcp.

Comment: I need to import it from my c# application so I don't want to use the bcp tool. I have a DataSet ready, just need to import it

Comment: @CyberK, you're the one asking for a **faster** solution. If you don't want to change what you already have, then by all means stick with your current solution. But then why ask the question? bcp can be called from your c# application with `Process.Start`. Saving a dataset with 160K rows will result in 160K individual insert statements. There is no way around that. The only ways to make that faster include disabling constraints and indices on the table and/or upgrading the host server, reducing network latency etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use make dataset xml using DataSet.getXml function. and pass input paremeter for SP.

for example

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.MyInsertSP
(
        @strXML varchar(1000) 
)
AS
Begin
    Insert into publishers
   Select     * from OpenXml(@intPointer,'/root/publisher',2)
    With     (pub_id char(4), pub_name varchar(40), city varchar(20), 
                  state char(2),9) country varchar(20))
    exec sp_xml_removedocument @intPointer
RETURN
End
```

Hope this make sense.